# Tadpole-free condition

Tags: string-theory, scattering, conformal-field-theory, moduli

Tadpole-free is a very important condition for perturbative string theory (which is equivalent to the theory to be expanded around the "right" vacuum). For simplicity, let's consider closed string only. 1-point insertion to a sphere vanish (for obvious reason, as the volume of the conformal group there is infinite), and for nonzero genus, it might be interesting.

Assume that the conformal invariance $Sp(2g, \mathbb{Z})$ condition (which is only needed to confirm for torus $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ modular invariant, and higher genus will follow) is satisfied.

How can I check for the disappearance of all 1-point insertion to the nonzero genus? Is it enough to check it for 1-point insertion to the torus, and higher genus will follow after that (just like with modular invariance)?

Can all these argument be generalized to worlsheets with boundaries (let's also include modular invariance condition here)?

Comment: I might be wrong about this, but I think $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$-invariance is the property of the spherical topology only (the conformal group there). It's not the same for nonzero genus and more complicated worldsheets.

Comment: As far as I know, different topology worldsheets have different conformal group. Maybe I misunderstand about what you mean by $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$-invariance here. Is there any materials I can found to read about this? Can it be generalized to worldsheets with boundaries?

Comment: How do higher-loop modular invariance follow from one-loop modular invariance?